# How to validate dataframe in pandera using multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandera

I have following dataframe. Need to validate dataframe to check if there exists rows with columns Name and tag both NULL at the same time.
I tried following - but index where it fails are 0 & 2.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import pandera as pa

 data = [['Alex',10,'t1'],['Bob',12,None],['Clarke',13,'t3'],[None,14,'t3'],[None,15,None]]
 df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age','Tag']) 
 schema = pa.DataFrameSchema(checks=pa.Check(lambda df: ~(pd.notnull(df["Name"])&pd.notnull(df["Tag"])) )
)

try:
    schema.validate(df)
except pa.errors.SchemaErrors as err:
    print("Schema errors and failure cases:")
    print(err.failure_cases)
```

I want above code to return index as 4. How should I create check for pandera schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the docs on [*`Handling null values`*](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/checks.html#handling-null-values),

> By default, pandera drops null values before passing the objects to
> validate into the check function. For Series objects null elements are
> dropped (this also applies to columns), and for DataFrame objects,
> rows with any null value are dropped.
>
> If you want to check the properties of a pandas data structure while
> preserving null values, specify Check(..., ignore_na=False) when
> defining a check.

That way, make sure to add `ignore_na=False`:

```
schema = pa.DataFrameSchema(checks=pa.Check(lambda df: 
                                           ~(df['Name'].isnull() & 
                                             df['Tag'].isnull()),
                            ignore_na=False))
```